# SearchConsole ライブドアブログ

Tags: google-app-engine

ライブドアブログの元のURL 『hoge.blog.jp』 から 『hoge.jp』に変更し、SearchConsole(WebMasterTool)に手順通りアドレス変更をしました。
SearchConsoleのヘルプには

＞サイトを新しいドメインまたはサブドメインに移転した場合は、Search Console のアドレス変更ツールを使用してください。アドレスの変更通知を利用すると、現在の Google 検索の掲載順位への影響を最小限に抑えながら、新しいアドレスの新しい URL をインデックスに登録するために必要な Google での移行プロセスを管理できます。

と記述されているのですが、３日立ってもGoogleから削除されています、site: hoge.jp で検索すると一つもありませんでした。

ここで質問なのですが、SearchConsoleのプロパティに元のURL『hoge.blog.jp』と新URL『hoge.jp』の２つがあります。
元のURLにはインデックスは当然登録されていますが、新URLにもサイトマップを送信すべきなのでしょうか？

プロパティは重複しているのですが、一体どうすればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この質問はGoogle App Engineではなく、Web Master Toolの質問だと思います。